# How to find Center of Mass for my entire binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, mathematical-morphology

I'm interested in finding the coordinates (X,Y) for my whole, entire binary image, and not the CoM for each component seperatly.
How can I make it efficiently?
I guess using regionprops, but couldn't find the correct way to do so.

Comment: You have the equation for the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moments#Examples), right? Have you tried coding that?

Comment: calculate the bounding box and then calculate centroid? (Because you don't want the centroid of individual components).

Comment: I have the equation, and calculating the bounding box won't consider holes and gaps between different components.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define all regions as a single region for `regionprops`

```
props = regionprops( double( BW ), 'Centroid' );
```

According to the data type of `BW` `regionprops` decides whether it should label each connected component as a different region or treat all non-zeros as a single region with several components.

---

Alternatively, you can compute the centroid by yourself

```
[y x] = find( BW );
cent = [mean(x) mean(y)];
```

Answer (score 6):

Just iterate over all the pixels calculate the average of their X and Y coordinate

```
void centerOfMass (int[][] image, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    int SumX = 0;
    int SumY = 0;
    int num  = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i<imageWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<imageHeight; j++)
        {
            if (image[i][j] == WHITE)
            {
               SumX = SumX + i;
               SumY = SumY + j; 
               num = num+1;
            }
        }
    }

    SumX = SumX / num;
    SumY = SumY / num;
    // The coordinate (SumX,SumY) is the center of the image mass
}
```

Extending this method to gray scale images in range of [0..255]: Instead of

```
if (image[i][j] == WHITE)
                {
                   SumX = SumX + i;
                   SumY = SumY + j; 
                   num = num+1;
                }
```

Use the following calculation

```
SumX = SumX + i*image[i][j];
SumY = SumY + j*image[i][j]; 
num = num+image[i][j];
```

In this case a pixel of value 100 has 100 times higher weight than dark pixel with value 1, so dark pixels contribute a rather small fraction to the center of mass calculation.
Please note that in this case, if your image is large you might hit a 32 bits integer overflow so in that case use `long int` sumX, sumY variables instead of `int`.

Comment: I know. but C/C++ is equal to java and can be read as plain English. So other people that stumble upon this question and use different programming language will still be able to understand the mathematical solution. I am sure that 'idow90' will be able to understand the algorithm and convert it to Matlab which is basically your answer

Comment: Shouldn't num increase even if the color is Black? 
Applying the formula for a grayscale image, should I add all non-black colors?

Comment: num counts the amount of overall white pixels. SumX and SumY count the integrals in X and Y directions. Dividing by total number of white pixels gives the correct answer. I extended the answer for grayscale images for your reguest